# Delete items on the contextual menu (right click)

Tags: shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

In this case, I only need help with the contextual menu which appears when you right click on a folder in Finder.

I would like to delete this two items:

- `Burn "folder" to disc...` and
- `Labels`. All the labels box with all the eight colors and the `x`.

I don't use any of them and they only quit me some space.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: This menu is actually called a contextual menu.

Comment: Some more searching led me to another thread on here with the same question but unfortunately the same response that  I gave you below.  Check it out though, maybe there's some insight for you.  [Remove entries from context menu](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72702/remove-entries-from-finders-context-menu)

Comment: @jbharper2 You are right. I hope some guru tells us a terminal command to do it. If not, I will remove the question as it is duplicated. Thank you.

Comment: Removing "Labels" section (now called "Tags"): https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387849/remove-tags-section-from-macos-finder-right-click-context-menu/

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to remove some items from The Finder's context menu in the Keyboard preference pane, it is not however possible to remove the specific ones you have asked about, at least as far as I can tell.  If you would like to try and remove some of the other items, go to System Preferences --> Keyboard and select the keyboard shortcuts tab.  Select "Services" from the list on the left hand side and then scroll down to the "Files & Folders" heading on the left hand side.  From here you can select which items to keep and which to remove.  As  I said, there is no option to remove "Burn" or "Labels" but at this point I don't think that is possible.  I'll certainly keep searching for you though.

Comment: The same as before, I am aware of that.

Answer (score -1):

[This might work.](http://www.chriswrites.com/2012/06/how-to-customise-the-right-click-menu-in-mac-os-x/)

I couldn't find Burn to disc or Labels there though. there might be a terminal command the I am unfamiliar with though.

Comment: I know this way, but as you said, there's no labels and burn there.